# Random effects when there are repeated measures for only *some* participants

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I'd be really grateful for some advice here. I apologise if this question is  rather elementary, but I'm not proficient at multilevel modeling (yet).

My question relates to a research problem in corpus linguistics. I’m looking at how frequently certain types of metaphor are used to describe musical properties in reviews of classical music CDs. More particularly, I want to see if these frequencies differ for different composers. (Let’s suppose they are Beethoven and Scriabin.)

However, I need to take into account the effect of the reviewer on metaphor frequency (e.g., some people use metaphors more often than others as an idiosyncratic feature of their writing style).

So I’ve got a fixed effect for ‘composer’ and a random effect for ‘reviewer’. The response variable is (metaphor) ‘frequency’.

If I had different reviewers associated with each composer, the model would be (a), with random intercepts only.

(a) frequency = composer + (1 | reviewer)

However, if I had the same set of reviewers associated with both composers, the model would be (b), with random intercepts and random slopes.

(b) frequency = composer + (1+composer | reviewer)

My problem is that, for example, the Beethoven reviews are authored by reviewers #1, #2, #3 and #4, while the Scriabin reviews are authored by reviewers #1, #3, #5 and #6. Note that only reviewers #1 and #3 author reviews associated with *both* composers.

Thus, I seem to have a scenario which is ‘between’ (a), with no repeated measures for ‘reviewer’, and (b), with repeated measures for ‘reviewer’.

Comment: How do the groups relate to the condition? I take it that Y specifies group 1 or group 2, but I don't see the conditions in model (a) and (b). Could you elaborate on the models? Seems to me that this is either a missing data or a multiple membership problem

Comment: Sorry Niek. In an attempt to simplify my question, I made it too vague. I've edited it considerably.

Comment: If you have enough reviewers and enough of them reviewed multiple composers, then you can fit the second model, even if a lot of them only reviewed one composer and/or only did one review.

Comment: Thanks Björn. It's likely that I won't have a large number of reviewers. Is there an alternative approach I can use in this case?